# Adding a Item to CheckedListBox in Form3 by clicking a button in Form2

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer

I'm having three Forms for Example Form1 ,Form2, Form3. Whenever i'm clicking a button in Form2 then it should add a item in CheckedListBox in Form3. In Form1 Whenever i'm clicking a button it should show me the updated CheckedListBox of Form3(i.e the updated checkedlistbox which is caused by clicking button in Form2). Can anyone help me out in this?

enter code here

Comment: What did you get so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Your tags make no sense. Is this WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: @Tieson.T it is in WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Singleton Factory class that would help in sharing your form objects with each  other as shown below:

```
public class FormFactory
{
    Dictionary<string, Form> forms = new Dictionary<string, Form>();
    private static FormFactory _factory;

    public void SetForm(string name, Form form)
    {
        forms[name] = form;
    }

    public Form GetForm(string name)
    {
        if (forms.ContainsKey(name))
            return forms[name];
        return null;
    }

    private FormFactory()
    {

    }

    static FormFactory()
    {
        _factory = new FormFactory();
    }

    public static FormFactory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _factory;
        }
    }
}
```

Change access modifiers of all controls that you wand to share from private to internal. For example :

```
internal System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkedListBox1;
```

Add form load method in every form as shown below for form1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormFactory.Instance.SetForm("Form1", this);
}
```

Now you can use below code for adding item in checkedListBox1 of Form3 on button1 click of Form2:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 form3 = FormFactory.Instance.GetForm("Form3") as Form1;
        if(form3!=null)
        {
            form3.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Item" + form3.checkedListBox1.Items.Count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **"EventAggregator pattern"** to solve this.